# Sharing Terraform provider binary across multiple configurations

Tags: terraform

I'm managing DNS records with Terraform, and currently all the zones are defined by .tf files in a single directory.  Running `plan` or `apply` will touch every record in every zone, which is becoming too slow and hitting the provider's rate limits.

I'd like to split the config on a per-zone basis, so each zone has its own Terraform config and (remote) state file.  Applying a change to a zone will affect only that one zone, not all of them.

Is it possible to somehow share the provider binary between these separate configurations?  It's ~20Mb and I don't want to commit 20 copies of it into git.  Symlinks might work, but are not portable.

If there's a Terraform configuration that supports this use case (multiple configurations that can be operated on independently), I'd love to understand what it is -- I haven't been able to find anything that fits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the [plugin cache directory](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#provider-plugin-cache) to have Terraform only download the plugin once for a specific version of it.

You can do this by setting the `TF_PLUGIN_CACHE_DIR` environment variable or setting `plugin_cache_dir` in your [Terraform configuration file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/cli-config.html) (`.terraformrc` or `terraform.rc`).

I've not seen it documented anywhere and it might be a hangover from before Terraform collapsed all the provider binaries into a single binary (before then breaking them out again in 0.11) but Terraform will also pick up any provider binaries in the same directory as the core Terraform binary as long as they are appropriately named.

So if you setup your machine like this:

```
# ls -l /usr/local/bin/terraform*
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root      69073632 Mar 20 18:08 /usr/local/bin/terraform
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      69884160 Mar 20 18:08 /usr/local/bin/terraform-provider-aws_v1.11.0_x4
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      11621440 Mar 20 18:08 /usr/local/bin/terraform-provider-null_v1.0.0_x4
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      18291026 Mar 20 18:08 /usr/local/bin/terraform-provider-postgresql_v0.1.0_x4
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      11685184 Mar 20 18:08 /usr/local/bin/terraform-provider-random_v1.1.0_x4
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      11711744 Mar 20 18:08 /usr/local/bin/terraform-provider-template_v1.0.0_x4
```

then Terraform won't attempt to download any binaries for these providers and versions.

You can use the [`terraform-bundle` command](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/tree/master/tools/terraform-bundle) to download a specific Terraform version and providers which can be useful if Terraform needs to be used in a restricted environment or to shave time off CI builds by saving having to redownload providers each time.